How to capture the response of form submit using Angular 17
I am working on an application where the flow is when I submit the form it posts the response to the URLRetour I need to capture the response before it redirected me to the URLRetour. Or how can we capture post-response in an angular component? Below is the code
   <form id="paymentForm">
        <input name="IdMerchant" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.IdMerchant" type="hidden" />
        <input name="IdSession" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.IdSession" type="hidden" />
        <input name="Amount" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.Amount" type="text" />
        <input name="Currency" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.Currency" type="hidden" />
        <input name="CCNumber" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.CCNumber" type="hidden" />
        <input name="CCExpDate" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.CCExpDate" type="hidden" />
        <input name="CVVCode" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.CVVCode" type="hidden" />
        <input name="EmailPorteur" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.EmailPorteur" type="hidden" />
        <input name="FirstName" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.FirstName" type="hidden" />
        <input name="LastName" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.LastName" type="hidden" />
        <input name="Address1" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.Address1" type="hidden" />
        <input name="City" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.City" type="hidden" />
        <input name="CountryCode" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.CountryCode" type="hidden" />
        <input name="TotalQuantity" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.TotalQuantity" type="hidden" />
        <input name="ChallengeIndicator" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.ChallengeIndicator" type="hidden" />
        <input name="URLRetour" [(ngModel)]="paymentFormValues.URLRetour" type="hidden" />
      
        <button (click)="submitForm()" value="">Continuer le paiement avec 3DS</button>
        <hr />
      </form>


Ts Code

  paymentFormValues: any = {
    IdMerchant: '38023277',
    IdSession: '097a4cc4-59e8-43a5-a767-c6865386ff5a',
    Amount: '20',
    Currency: '978',
    CCNumber: '5425233430109903',
    CCExpDate: '0426',
    CVVCode: '123',
    EmailPorteur: 't.ablancourt@trm.re',
    FirstName: 'Thomas',
    LastName: 'ABLANCOURT',
    Address1: '1 rue de ici',
    City: 'Saint Denis',
    CountryCode: 'FR',
    TotalQuantity: '1',
    ChallengeIndicator: '02',
    URLRetour: 'https://gateway-dev.mvola.mg:443/selfcarepaymentapi/v1/api/callback/Transaction/postResponse'
  };

  submitForm() {
    const form = document.getElementById('paymentForm') as HTMLFormElement;
    form.action = 'https://preprod-tpeweb.paybox.com/cgi/RemoteMPI.cgi';
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.submit();
  }


In order to catch the response of your POST API route, you need to subscribe your http call.
I strongly recommand your to do that in a angular service like this :
payment.service.ts:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentService{

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  public submitPayment(paymentForm:any) : Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('https://preprod-tpeweb.paybox.com/cgi/RemoteMPI.cgi',paymentForm);
  }
}

Then in your component you can subscribe to your API call via an Observable :
payment-form.component.ts:
export class PaymentFormComponent{
 constructor(private paymentService:PaymentService){}

 paymentFormValues: any = {
    IdMerchant: '38023277',
    IdSession: '097a4cc4-59e8-43a5-a767-c6865386ff5a',
    Amount: '20',
    Currency: '978',
    CCNumber: '5425233430109903',
    CCExpDate: '0426',
    CVVCode: '123',
    EmailPorteur: 't.ablancourt@trm.re',
    FirstName: 'Thomas',
    LastName: 'ABLANCOURT',
    Address1: '1 rue de ici',
    City: 'Saint Denis',
    CountryCode: 'FR',
    TotalQuantity: '1',
    ChallengeIndicator: '02',
    URLRetour: 'https://gateway-dev.mvola.mg:443/selfcarepaymentapi/v1/api/callback/Transaction/postResponse'
  };

 submitForm() {
    this.paymentService.submitPayment(this.paymentFormValues).subscribe({
     next:(response) => {
       console.log(response)
       //your code logic to redirect to URLRetour
     }
   })
  }
}


When the form is submitted it automatically redirect to the URLRetour
